# Regex for Email validation in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the below Regex pattern for validating Email Ids.

```
String EMAIL_REGEXP = "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
```

Here I want to restrict the special characters in start of the String. But with this above regex its accepting the special character at start. See the below test case

```
@ParameterizedTest
  @ValueSource(strings = {"#test123@gmail.com", "!test123@gmail.com",
          "`test123@gmail.com", "~test123@gmail.com",
          "$test123@gmail.com", "#test123@gmail.com"})
  //@Test
  void test_EmailCheck(String emailId){
    String EMAIL_REGEXP = "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
    System.out.println(emailId);
    assertTrue(emailId.matches(EMAIL_REGEXP));
  }
```

Its returning all true here, see below screenshot
[image]

I want to restrict all special characters at start of the string, apart from this issue all other things working as expected. Please give me some solution. Thanks

Comment: use a negative look ahead. `"^(?![special characters here])"`

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't even bother with anything more complicated than `^[^@]+@[^@]+$`. Your regex accepts consecutive dots, does not check length of local part and domain, and even if the email address is syntactically valid, doesn't mean it exists or belongs to the person that entered it. If you're doing email signups, do double opt-in by sending a confirmation email to the provided address and only add people that click the confirmation link in that email. If this is not about signup, I'd be very careful to let people email others through my system. It can ruin your reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a matching group for the first character that excludes symbols, like so. This ensures that only alphanumeric characters can start the string

```java
String EMAIL_REGEXP = "(?:[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])";
```